# How can I overlap two images, rotate the top one displaying only one part of it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to rotate a card, on hover, the effect I want to achieve is that the image background of the card which is the same as the entire page background sort of comes out and rotate with the card.

Just like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IM7YWJ0U6Vs&t=314s

[image]

I have tried using the image background twice, but I can find a way to hide the rest of the background image.

This is what I have tried, in the snippet to be more exact what I am trying to do is make the leaves rotate on hover along with the card.

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477414348463-c0eb7f1359b6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.inner {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477414348463-c0eb7f1359b6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80;);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 80px;
}

.card-wrap {
  width: 240px;
  height: 280px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3vw;
    padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}


.card-wrap:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72) 0 0 32px 5px;
  transform: rotate(12deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <ul class="inner" id="inner">
        <li class="card-wrap" id="card-wrap">
          <span class="card">
            <img
              class="icon"
              src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/soil.png"
            />
            <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
            <p>
              Pasture he invited mr company shyness. But when shot real her.
            </p>
          </span>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to hide the non needed part using a big shadow:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477414348463-c0eb7f1359b6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 80px;
}


.card-wrap {
  width: 240px;
  height: 280px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3vw;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  box-shadow:
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0 0 32px 5px,
        0 0 0 calc(100vh + 100vw) #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.card-wrap:hover {
  box-shadow: 
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72) 0 0 32px 5px,
        0 0 0 calc(100vh + 100vw) #fff;
  transform: rotate(12deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="inner" id="inner">
    <li class="card-wrap" id="card-wrap">
      <span class="card">
            <img
              class="icon"
              src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/soil.png"
            />
            <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
            <p>
              Pasture he invited mr company shyness. But when shot real her.
            </p>
          </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that is a great idea, but there are two more things that still don't work. I should be able to rotate the inner background  when I hover and the container background should come forward, I am trying to use z-index but does not seem to do anything